# JavaScript Globalize: How to compare two dates?

Tags: javascript, html, date, globalization

I would like to compare two dates.

**Problem**: The date and time strings are formatted by [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize). So, I'm not able to split the values the same way and have to differenciate everytime.

I would like to have a function like...

```
Globalize.getTimestamp("21.12.2012 19:41", "d t") // value, pattern
```

...but cannot find it.

That's the form:

```
<label>From</label>
<input type="text" name="start_date" value="21.12.2012" class="datepicker"/>
<input type="text" name="start_time" value="19:41" class="timepicker"/>

<label>To</label>
<input type="text" name="end_date" value="22.12.2012" class="datepicker"/>
<input type="text" name="end_time" value="19:41" class="timepicker"/>
```

**Edit**:
That's how to parse the date:

```
Globalize.parseDate($("[name='start_date']").val()); // 21.12.2012
```

But parsing the date with time doesn't work:

```
Globalize.parseDate($("[name='start_date']").val() + " " + $("[name='start_time']").val()); // 21.12.2012 19:41
```

I'd like to avoid developing the Globalize.getTimestamp()-function. How would you solve this problem? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Which locale are you using? You should read using the same locale as was used when writing.

Answer (score 2):

If the strings have been written using Globalize, you should read them using Globalize, with the same locale (culture). After calling Globalize.parseDate(), you have Date objects that can easily be compared.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention parseDate is working but not with time. I updated my post!